# param is missing or the value is empty: category

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to create a new Category based on the title of the 'grow' that im creating (for a garden management tool'

But Im getting the following error:

'param is missing or the value is empty: category'

[edit] this is how the code is fixed.  As per the suggestion in the comments:

remove the `@grow = Grow.new(grow_params.merge(category: Category.create(cat_params)))`

and replace with `@grow = Grow.new(grow_params)`

and in the Grow model add

`after_create do
    Category.create(name: self.title)
  end`

and its fixed.

```
class GrowsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_grow, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


def index
  @grows = Grow.all
end


def show
end


def new
  @grow = Grow.new
end


def edit
end


def create
  @grow = Grow.new(grow_params.merge(category: Category.create(cat_params)))

  respond_to do |format|
    if @grow.save
      format.html { redirect_to @grow, notice: 'Grow was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @grow }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @grow.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /grows/1
# PATCH/PUT /grows/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @grow.update(grow_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @grow, notice: 'Grow was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @grow }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @grow.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /grows/1
# DELETE /grows/1.json
def destroy
  @grow.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to grows_url, notice: 'Grow was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
   end
  end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

  def set_grow
    @grow = Grow.find(params[:id])
  end
  def cat_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name)
  end
    def grow_params
      params.require(:grow).permit(:title, :notes, :category_id)
    end
  end
```

I simply want to pass in the grow.title to new category name
However im not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `create` method leave the statement to be 
`@grow = Grow.new(grow_params)`

and in your `Grow` model, write an `after_create` callback

within which you create your `Category` like `Category.create(name: self.title)`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it up nicely.

Comment: If I wanted to destroy the category when I delete the grow, would I just do after_destroy and use the same argument?  -  Category.destroy(name: self.title)

Comment: well, you could do that. But i'd prefer use `dependent: :destroy` for your association.